# Process Builder not firing

Tags: process-builder

I created a process builder that updates a start date based on the Opp Close Date and the end date based on that start date plus number of months in another field on the opp object. It fires when the custom object record is new, but I need it to retrigger whenever the close date is changed to reconfigure the dates. That is not working.

My criteria for the action group is:

```
AND(
ISCHANGED([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.CloseDate ),
NOT(CONTAINS( TEXT([Campaign_Design_Profile__c].Related_Opportunity__c.Type), 
"Rollover"))
)
```

Comment: On which object this process builder is added? Seems that you are having this on `Campaign_Design_Profile__c` and you are checking `ischanged()` for its parent object i.e. Opportunity. basically, It will not fire when the value on the parent is changed.

Comment: Correct. I added a formula field to the Campaign_Design_Profile__c object for the Opp Close Date so I can use the ISCHANGED function on that field instead. Is this the appropriate solution? It doesn't appear to be triggering with this change either.

Comment: @Luara You need to write this process builder on Opportunity like whenever start date is changed, it will update the end date, and if you want the same on Campaign_Design_Profile__c you can use your formula field.

Comment: I created the Requested Start and Requested Completion Dates on the opp object and created the process builder with action criteria:                          
AND(ISCHANGED([Opportunity].CloseDate  ),
NOT(CONTAINS( TEXT([Opportunity].Type ), "Rollover")))    This is still not updating the Requested Start and Requested Completion dates.

Comment: did you activate the process builder?

Comment: Yes. It is active on the Opp process and inactive on my original CDP process.